# Strange new error in SSIS when working drive and executable drive are different

Tags: powershell, ssis

I'm using Visual Studio 2008 to code a new package that simply call a powershell script to load a csv file in a database.

The issue I'm facing is that when I'm create an "Execute Process Task" I got and the error: 0xc0029151, because the powershell exe is in drive C: and my powershell script is in drive D:.

If I copy paste the powershell binaries in D: drive, every thing works well.

This strange because I've got another SSIS that do the same task and this one is runnin well.

Note: looks like somewhere I need set a "cd /D" setting to change the drive...

Comment: We need more details. How do you have the `execute process task` configured for both the working and non-working versions? What is your script doing?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `0xc0029151` is not strange, and certainly not a new error.
It's `DTS_E_EXECPROCTASK_PROCESSEXITCODEEXCEEDS` which means that process exit code was other that expected. In other words, the script itself may not be working, or powershell call be incorrect.

If the script is fine, then try to run entire command from cmd (that is powershell.exe with your script location as parameter - I assume that's the way you're running it in the task).

If it's working, then there may be another reason. Execute Process Task has WorkingDirectory parameter, but it's not being set for your .ps1, but rather for powershell.exe (because that's what you're running in you task), while your script may still have different directory set for it.
Just in case add `Set-Location` in your script and see what happens.